# queryPurchases in case of no internet connection

Tags: android, kotlin, play-billing-library

I'm using the following code to check, whether the user has paid for the subscription and/or wether it is expired.

```
     val subscriptionResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS)
            if (subscriptionResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
// User is allowed to to access the content
```

This works perfect, but how do I check this, if the user has NO internet connection? I can't restrict the access, just because he has no internet connection - so what do you do? Store the period the user is supposed to have access locally on the device?
Any suggestion is mostly appreciated!

Comment: I think storing locally in a shared preferences or a local database is the best way to go.

Comment: thx for your answer, do you know, wether this would be than best practise? It sounds a little bit strange to me, but on the other hand I have no other idea..

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are giving the user offline access to your subscription items. In that case, yes, you have to store the entitlement locally. It is best practice. You can use SharedPref or you can do as shown in [processPurchases](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/kotlin/trivialdrive/billingrepo/BillingRepository.kt) using Room.